# RootView on React Native 0.73.2

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement the Apple External Accessory Framework in order to configure a WAC accessory on React Native. I can start the search(and find accessories) and stop it but when I try to configure it no Native Modal is showing up in my React Native Application. I followed the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eawifiunconfiguredaccessorybrowser/configureaccessory:withconfigurationuionviewcontroller:?language=objc and everything seems to be fine, I think the only problem is that I cannot get the right RootViewController from React Native to use it with the framework.

So the question is, how to access the RootViewController in RN0.73.2 to be able to use it with  the EA Method

```
- (void) configureAccessory:(EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessory *) accessory 
withConfigurationUIOnViewController:(UIViewController *) viewController;
```